# Converting List of lists to Stream - Functional Programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming, recursive-datastructures

I am working on Scala to convert list of lists to list of customized object "Point"

```
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
   var cX: Int = x
   var cY: Int = y
  }
```

Should I use Foreach or should I use Map or foreach in this case

```
def list_To_Point(_listOfPoints :List[List[String]]) : List[Point] = { 

    var elem = 
    lazy val _list:  List[Point] = _listOfPoints.map(p=> new Point(p[0],p[1])
      _list
  }
```

I couldn't figure out where the problem exactly ?

Comment: why not use a tuple for the inner structure?

Comment: I don't think that I need that as they are all asame . I need to know how can I push a new object of point in the list everytime

Answer (score 4):

```
 def listToPoint(l:List[List[String]]):List[Point] = 
     l.collect({case x::y::Nil => new Point(x.toInt,y.toInt)})
```

But you really shouldn't use a List[String] to represent what is basically `(Int,Int)` …

Answer (score 1):

ugly as hell and untested but it should work (pls consider making your structures immutable) :

```
case class Point(x:Int,y:Int) 




object Point {


  def listToPoint(listOfPoints:List[List[String]]):List[Point] =
    listOfPoints.map(p => new Point(p(0).toInt,p(1).toInt))
}
```